# How would I blit something before another thing in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering how I could blit an image before another image depending on their y position. I want to make a game like pokemon, where if you are behind somethin, it appears over you (it has blitted after you), but if you are in front of it, it blits before you. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need to track each sprites z-position and have your draw function blit the sprites in order. What have you tried so far and what difficulties have you encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in pygame, the image that is blitted last has priority over others, resulting in that image being displayed on top of all others. Here is an example:

```
import pygame

Img1 = pygame.image.load('Number1.png')
Img2 = pygame.image.load('Number2.png')

pygame.init()
#Initiate screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
done = False

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:                    
                        done = True
        #Blit the images
        screen.blit(Img1,(200,200))
        screen.blit((Img2),(300,300))

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Since we blitted the number2 after the number 1, the number2 will be blitted ontop of the number 1 as shown below.
[Click this link for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QBCC.png)

Comment: Thanks, so i would check the y coordinates of each image before i blit them, and then do it in a certain order depending on their coordinates?

Comment: not sure if this answer covers the OP's issue. Sure, you can blit something after to make sure it renders ontop of other objects, but what if you walk behind an object? You'd want that object to blit infront of you, until you walk infront of it and then it'd blit behind you...